# Using Anchor In Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, anchor

I am trying to program a juke box however I am at early stages and I have come across a problem when using `anchor`.

Here is my code;

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox as box



def main_menu():
    window = Tk()
    window.title('Juke Box')
    window.geometry('800x480')
    window.configure(background = 'black')

    label = Label(window, text = 'Juke-Box', fg = 'light green', bg = 'black', font = (None, 30), height = 2)
    label.pack(side = TOP)

    Jam = Button(window, text = 'The Jam', width = 25, height = 2)
    Jam.pack(pady = 10, padx = 25, anchor = 'w')

    Roses = Button(window, text = 'The Stone Roses', width = 25, height = 2)
    Roses.pack(pady = 10, padx = 25, anchor = 'w')

    Smiths = Button(window, text = 'The Smiths', width = 25, height = 2)
    Smiths.pack(pady = 10, padx = 25, anchor = 'w')

    Wedding = Button(window, text = 'The Wedding Pressent', width = 25, height = 2)
    Wedding.pack(pady = 10, padx = 25, anchor = 'w')

    Blondie = Button(window, text = 'Blondie', width = 25, height = 2)
    Blondie.pack(pady = 10, padx = 25, anchor = 'w')

    Clash = Button(window, text = 'Clash', width = 25, height = 2)
    Clash.pack(pady = 10, padx = 25, anchor = 'w')

    Madness = Button(window, text = 'Madness', width = 25, height = 2)
    Madness.pack(pady = 10, padx = 25, anchor = 'n')

    Pistols = Button(window, text = 'The Sex Pistols', width = 25, height = 2)
    Pistols.pack(pady = 10, padx = 25, anchor = 'n')

    window.mainloop()



main_menu()
```

My problem is because I have ran out of room when stacking my albums down the left I want to start stacking them down the middle so I used `anchor = 'n'` however it moved them all to the bottom.

Please could someone help me find a way to start stacking my albums from the top middle.

I am using python 3.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For the kind of thing you want to do, the `grid` geometry seems like a much better idea, you can explicitly code where the item will be rather than let the `pack` geometry implicitly determine where it will go.
Another improvement, would be to have a `Frame` where you put each album `Button`.
I have edited your piece of code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox as box

def main_menu():
    window = Tk()
    window.title('Juke Box')
    window.geometry('800x480')
    window.configure(background = 'black')

    label = Label(window, text = 'Juke-Box', fg = 'light green',
                  bg = 'black', font = (None, 30), height = 2)
    label.pack(side = TOP)

    gridFrame = Frame(window, bg='black') # New frame to store buttons

    # Grid uses sticky instead of anchor, but in this scenario it is not really necessary
    # I have left it in case you need it for some other reason

    Jam = Button(gridFrame, text = 'The Jam', width = 25, height = 2)
    Jam.grid(row=0, column=0, pady = 10, padx = 25, sticky=W) 
    Roses = Button(gridFrame, text = 'The Stone Roses', width = 25, height = 2)
    Roses.grid(row=1, column=0, pady = 10, padx = 25, sticky=W)

    Smiths = Button(gridFrame, text = 'The Smiths', width = 25, height = 2)
    Smiths.grid(row=2, column=0, pady = 10, padx = 25, sticky =W)

    Wedding = Button(gridFrame, text = 'The Wedding Pressent', width = 25, height = 2)
    Wedding.grid(row=3, column=0, pady = 10, padx = 25, sticky =W)

    Blondie = Button(gridFrame, text = 'Blondie', width = 25, height = 2)
    Blondie.grid(row=4, column=0, pady = 10, padx = 25, sticky =W)

    Clash = Button(gridFrame, text = 'Clash', width = 25, height = 2)
    Clash.grid(row=5, column=0, pady = 10, padx = 25, sticky =W)

    Madness = Button(gridFrame, text = 'Madness', width = 25, height = 2)
    Madness.grid(row=0, column=1, pady = 10, padx = 25, sticky =N)

    Pistols = Button(gridFrame, text = 'The Sex Pistols', width = 25, height = 2)
    Pistols.grid(row=1, column=1, pady = 10, padx = 25, sticky =N)

    gridFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM) 
    # Place it a the bottom or top or wherever you want it to go

    window.mainloop()

main_menu()
```

Here is a screenshot of how it looks like with the grid geometry:

[image: Juke Box Grid Geometry]

Is this what you wanted?

Hope it helped ^^

Comment: Thankyou , this is defiantly what I wanted helps slot :)

Comment: glad to be of use ^^