# Is there a way to iteratively create and pack buttons vertically in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there a way to iteratively create and pack buttons vertically in Tkinter?
I insist on using pack(), but its not treating me well.

```
def app_buttons(amt):

for i in range(amt + 1):
    tk.Button(root,
              width=15,
              height=2,
              relief='solid',
              borderwidth=1,
              text=f'App No.{i+1}',
              font=("Century Gothic", 16),
              ).pack(side='left',padx=20)
```

This creates 'n' buttons side-by-side instead of stacked vertically.

Comment: There is no question in your question. It's hard to answer a question that we can't see. Also if you want the buttons to be in a grid use the `.grid` geometry manager.

Comment: Remove `side='left'`.

Comment: Please fix your formatting.

Comment: Thanks @acw1668. It works just right!

Comment: Are you aware that you can do `side='top'`?

Comment: @BryanOakley Thank you. That also works, but it doesn't give the desired effect. I would like the buttons to be vertically stacked and left-aligned. I'm still not sure how to do this.

Comment: Then add `anchor='w'` to `.pack(...)`.

Comment: It is now that I feel silly! Thank you @acw1668!

Comment: Are you aware that if `amt` is 10, there will be 11 buttons created.  Is it what you expect?

Comment: _"That also works, but it doesn't give the desired effect."_ - using `side="top"` and not having `side` defined at all will yield identical results (ie: the default is "top" if you don't specify it)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Anchor In Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35812894/using-anchor-in-tkinter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your code (I had to remove `before=app_button`; it'
s not defined). I also removed `side='left'`, and it works.

```
for i in range(amt + 1):
    tk.Button(root,
              width=15,
              height=2,
              relief='solid',
              borderwidth=1,
              text=f'App No.{i+1}',
              font=("Century Gothic", 16),
              ).pack(padx=20)
```

Edit: Since you want to keep it on the left side, does this help? However this keeps the buttons on the top-left corner.

```
for i in range(amt + 1):
    tk.Button(root,
              width=15,
              height=2,
              relief='solid',
              borderwidth=1,
              text=f'App No.{i+1}',
              font=("Century Gothic", 16),
              ).pack(padx=20, anchor='w')
```

Comment: Thank you! This works just right. I would still like to keep them pushed to the left, however.

Comment: I'll find a way to do that hopefully.

Comment: Add this parameter or option - `.pack(anchor='w')`, this will keep your buttons stacked vertically and aligned towards the left

Comment: Does using `anchor='w'` help?

Comment: Sorry @PCM I didn't see your comment first.

Comment: @DaniyalWarraich, yes it works. Hopefully it answers the question.